# parseInt() or int equivalent for C

Tags: javascript, python, c

I'm learning C just started today and I'm coming from knowing a bit of Python and a little bit of Javascript and I want to know how I would get the int base of a string for example in Javascript you can do this:

```
parseInt("myString", 36);
```

That would return `1799765255212`

In Python it would be this:

```
int("myString", 36)
```

Which would also return `1799765255212`

Is there a C equivalent? If not, how would I make one?

Answer (score 2):

```
#inclucde <stdlib.h>

long long val = strtoll("myString", NULL, 36);
```

Comment: `strtoll` added since C99.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strtoll](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) which accepts an optional base to convert your number to base36 as Python's `int` would have done

```
long long myint1 = std::strtoll("myString", NULL ,36);
```

Few things to note,

Python Integers are not limitted to C/C++ bitness limit. As per standard, size of `int` is atmost 4 bytes

[std::stoi, std::stol, std::stoll](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) unlike `atoi` accepts an optional base to accept strings in arbitrary base.

So consider the above two points, `std::strtoll` works best for your particular case.

**Sample Source**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "myString";
    long long myint1 = std::strtoll(str1.c_str(),0,36);
    std::cout << "std::strtoll(\"" << str1 << "\") is " << myint1 << '\n';
}
```

*Output*

```
std::strtoll("myString") is 1799765255212
```

**Note** `strtoll` was added to standard per C99 or C++11. As of now, not all compilers are C++11 compliant

Answer (score 0):

I would use `strtoll` like:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

long long value;
value = strtoll("myString", NULL, 36);
printf("value is %lld.\n", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [atof()](http://www.dsm.fordham.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi.pl?topic=atof&ampsect=3) or [sscanf()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf) for this purpose in addition to [strtod()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod)